# Class ID not syntax colour coded in CSS

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

I've issue with Sublime Text 3.

**Question:** At line 76 why is `#about` not purple like `#logo_text_box_line` at line 64?

[image]

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, its place is not on stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @LioraHaydont - Please read the second part of this statement from the SO help files carefully - "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**." - Text editors are **tools used primarily for programming** so questions about them **are** in scope for SO. - This question should be closed but **not** for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

Your closing curly brace is back to front on line 72, is: `{` but should be: `}`